# cannot read property setNumber of undefined getting in Unit testing error

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit testing my code where I am getting the below error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setNumber' of undefined

this is my service method for that

```
 setNumber(number) {
   this.number = number;
 }
```

This code is there in ts

```
this.dataService.setNumber(null);
```

This is my spec code.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
   const spyDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DataService', ['setNumber'])
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, MatDialogModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, RouterTestingModule, MatMenuModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTableModule, MatSortModule, MatIconModule, MatCardModule,],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  providers: [

    { provide: DataService, useValue: spyDataService },
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
    { provide: LayoutUtilsService, useValue: {} }

  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
  .compileComponents();
```

}));

```
  it('should be create data service', () => {
   expect(service.setNumber).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
 });
```

What is wrong here why I am getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setNumber' of undefined

Comment: Wait a minute, do you `expect(service.setNumber).to//...`, but haven't declared the variable `service` anywhere? Or is something still missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mock the `dataService` `setNumber` method inside beforeEach of the testing portion.

```
// const mockDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('YourServiceName', ['methodname']);
const mockDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DataService', ['setNumber']);
```

After this you need to use this mockDataservice inside the providers array of testing module.

```
providers: [
  {provide: Dataservice, useValue: mockDataService }
]



it('should be create data service', () => {
   expect(service.setNumber).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
 });
```

Comment: I already have this line in my code 
const spyDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DataService', ['setNumber'])

 { provide: DataService, useValue: spyDataService }, Still I am getting the same error

Comment: I have edited my answer with spec. I hope you are retrieving service instance in similar way. I would suggest you to write complete test file code and error screenshot

Comment: Yes let service: DataService

Comment: when does this statement executes -> this.dataService.setNumber(null); ?? Is it inside any method ?? Please provide code of that method and how are you initialiing service and test file

Comment: Yes inside ngoninit(): void {
this.dataService.setNumber(null)
}

Comment: Iam getting error in get method if I mention get(DataService)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221749/discussion-between-princeisninja-and-mahadevan).